# With gnu find, what is the difference between -print0 and -printf "%p\0"

Tags: find, ruby, null

In a terminal I can run...

```
find . -type f -print0
./testdir/testfile2.txt./testdir/testfile.txt
```

And then...

```
find . -type f -printf "%p\0"
./testdir/testfile2.txt./testdir/testfile.txt
```

They both visually appear the same, but since this is about the null character, that doesn't say much.  If I run via the ruby repl:

```
2.5.1 :001 > `find . -type f -print0`
 => "./testdir/testfile2.txt\u0000./testdir/testfile.txt\u0000"
```

and then

```
2.5.1 :002 > `find . -type f -printf "%p\0"`
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        2: from (irb):2
        1: from (irb):2:in ``'
ArgumentError (string contains null byte)
```

What is the difference in what the `-print0` option outputs vs `printf`?

Test system info:

uname: `Linux XPS-15-9570 4.15.0-30-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 26 17:42:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

ruby: `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There should be no difference. Pipe the output through `cat -v` which will escape non-printable characters.

Perhaps you have some special locale settings, which modifies what `-print0` does. At least with my en_US.UTF-8 settings there is no difference. Perhaps add the output of `locale` to your question.

Possibly your test with ruby causes ruby to interpret the `\0` itself, and `find` is not even executed.

Comment: Your theory about this invalid ruby test was correct.  Thanks!  Running the same test, but properly escaping the `\0` in ruby did the trick.  The following ruby then evaluates to true: `find . -type f -printf "%p\\0"` == `find . -type f -print0`